# CustomTkinter How to request data from a user?

Tags: customtkinter

`class Auth(customtkinter.CTk):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**()
self.geometry("400x500")
self.title("Авторизуйтесь!")
self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

```
    self.auth_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")

    def register_button():
        self.register_button.pack_forget()

        self.login_button.pack_forget()

        register_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        register_frame.pack(padx=135, pady=200)

        global nick_entry
        self.nick_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(register_frame, text="Nickname:")
        self.nick_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.nick_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(register_frame)
        
        self.nick_entry.pack(pady=10)

        global password_entry
        self.password_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(register_frame, text="Password:")
        self.password_label.pack(pady=10)

        self.password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(register_frame, show="*")
        self.password_entry.pack(pady=10)

        self.confirm_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(register_frame, text="Подтвердить регистрацию", command=submit_button)
        self.confirm_button.pack(pady=10)

    def submit_button():
        nickname = nick_entry.get()
        password = password_entry.get()

        user_data = {
            "nickname": nickname,
            "password": password
        }

        with open("db/users.json", "r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        data.append(user_data)

        with open("db/users.json", "w") as file:
            json.dump(data, file)

        nick_entry.delete(0, "end")
        password_entry.delete(0, "end")

        app = App()
        app.mainloop()
    
    self.register_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.auth_frame, text="Register", command=register_button)
    self.register_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.login_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.auth_frame, text="Login", command=lambda: print("Login button clicked"))
    self.login_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    self.auth_frame.pack()`
```

Написал вот такой код, мне нужно спросить у пользователя его данные ( NickName, Password ), как это сделать? Мой код просто не работает.

Я пробовал многие варианты решения этой проблемы в конечном итоге пришёл к этому коду и он не работает.